# How to loop changing text in HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I use HTML/Javascript to make text change, looping through a predetermined sequence?

[Kind of like this, but in text form, instead of GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhYyW.gif)

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and then we can help you fix it.

Comment: @RJM This is part of a bigger script I've written, but what the desired result is is displayed in the GIF file I've linked. I can't provide what I've tried because I don't know where to begin.

Comment: @rwu6 That's a bit confusing...`This is part of a bigger script I've written` -->  `I don't know where to begin`. It sounds like you've written it and need to find out what did it.

Comment: @Hodrobond Sorry for the confusion, what I meant was I wanted to know how to write the code to do what is represented in the GIF file, which will be part of a longer script I've already written to be rendered as a website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    <script>
        var example = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

        textSequence(0);
        function textSequence(i) {

            if (example.length > i) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = example[i];
                    textSequence(++i);
                }, 1000); // 1 second (in milliseconds)

            } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
                textSequence(0);
            }

        }
    </script>
```

And the div to show the sequence:

```
<div id="sequence"></div>
```